# Whenever I click sumbit on my form the page goes to my PHP page where I have my code.

Tags: php, jquery

Looking for a way to prevent page from going to my PHP page after clicking submit. You can see the form for yourself  if you got to http://zaryquiz.com/

Comment: Use ajax for form submission or give redirection in index2.php to the required location after completing the process

Answer (score 0):

The 'action' attribute of your form tells the form where to submit:

```
<form method="post" action="page_you_want_to_submit_to.php">
```

Yours points to 'index2.php' so that is where it is going. Where do you want it to go?